# Excel VBA for selecting an entire column starting from a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

How do I select the entire column after a specific cell?

For example, I would like to select the entire column after `C24` so that includes `C24, C25, ...`

I have worked with the following snippet with no success:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C24", ActiveSheet.Range("C24").End(xlDown)).Select
```

Could someone please correct my error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to wrap the two references within a `Range`:

```
Range(ActiveSheet.Range("C24"), ActiveSheet.Range("C24").End(xlDown)).Select
```

Comment: As noted by the answer from Doug, this will only select the entire rest of the column if it is either entirely blank or entirely filled.

Comment: Will Doug's method select the entire column regardless of whether it was completely blank/filled?

Comment: It doesn't select the entire column if it isn't completely filled. I can't find an alternative to .End . What else is there?

Answer (score 8):

Here's an approach that will work even if there are cells with content below C24:

```
With ActiveSheet
.Range(.Range("C24"), .Range("C" & .Rows.Count)).Select
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you want a formula for it or if any method will work but if you select the cell you want it to start on and hold ctrl+shift+down arrow it will select that cell and everything below it.