# Is it possible to Intersect a column starting from a specific cell with 3 arguments?

Tags: excel, vba, intersection

I want to select an entire column starting from F15.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)                                                         
    Dim KeyCells As Range                                                                                   
    Set KeyCells = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("F15"), Range("F15").End(xlDown))                                          
    If KeyCells Is Nothing Then                                                                             
        'No code since nothing should happen
    Else
        'Some Code
    End If
End Sub
```

I found a similar question however it does not work:
[Excel VBA for selecting an entire column starting from a specific cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166510/excel-vba-for-selecting-an-entire-column-starting-from-a-specific-cell)

Comment: `Range("F15"), Range("F15").End(xlDown)` ---> `Range(Range("F15"), Range("F15").End(xlDown))`. You need an outer `Range` call.

Comment: Thanks BigBen it worked. How can I highlight your answer ?

Comment: You can just [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here.

Answer (score -1):

BigBen found the answer:

Range("F15"), Range("F15").End(xlDown) ---> Range(Range("F15"), Range("F15").End(xlDown)). You need an outer Range call.

Basically just put the two ranges into one range. range(range1, range2)